# First steps on loading data into Cassandra with dsbulk

Tags: cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

I am following this guide on setting up dsbulk: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkSimpleLoad.html

I'm getting confused at this part:

```
dsbulk load -url export.csv -k ks1 -t table1 \ 
  -b "path/to/secure-connect-database_name.zip" \
  -u database_user -p database_password -header true
```

Where is that `secure-connect-database_name.zip` or how should i generate this?

I'm not all keen on using the method above so if there would be a way to just pass all the parameters in a command, that would work better for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the first line is something specific to DataStax Astra. If you're loading to an Astra instance, you would find the secure connect bundle downloadable from the database dashboard in Astra console.

If you are using DS Bulk for Cassandra, DSE, or any other compatible API, you do not need to be concerned with the secure connect bundle. You should be able to pass every parameter you need on the command line, or written in a config file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comment. Updated the docs, adding an **Important** note with info about the secure connect bundle ZIP and a related topic link. Might need to refresh your browser view to see the updates.

- https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkSimpleLoad.html
- https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkSimpleUnload.html

Comment: Page not found!